# Driver jdbc no funciona correctamente

Tags: jdbc, android-asynctask

> Porque no me conecta el driver?

```
   protected Boolean doInBackground(String[]... strings) {
        boolean respuesta=false;

        try {
            Class.forName("con.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://3.30.194.171:3306/tienda24","user24", "");
```

> No me realiza este if, el host y usuario estan bien

```
            if (conexion!=null){
                respuesta=true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```

> Me salta el toast de no funciona

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean respuesta) {
        super.onPostExecute(respuesta);
        if(respuesta){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Funciona", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Funciona", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

> Parece que el DriverManager.getConnection no hace su trabajo correctamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> El problema era de sintaxis

```
Class.forName("con.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

> Esta mal escrito, es:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```